# How to compare 2 specific processors with the same benchmark side by side?

Tags: cpu, performance, benchmarking

I want to compare my old AMD Phenom X4 9500 with the new Intel Core i5 8400 to see how much faster the new Intel processor is. Does anyone know of a website that can compare those two processors side by side using the same benchmark? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @dsstorefile Thanks, but is it the same benchmark on both CPUs? Meaning are they benchmarked with the same method and the Core i5 8400 is 6,7 times faster?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The Passmark comparison site](https://www.cpubenchmark.net/compare/) should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks, I was able to compare them side by side, it wasn't working yesterday, I don't know why.

Comment: +1 Short answer! Useful content!